# Updating Core Data Properties WITHOUT using Table Views

Tags: ios, core-data, getter-setter

I have a POS type app that uses Core Data to store daily sales transactions using table views. I am attempting to retrieve and update certain Core Date Properties, like daily sales counts, WITHOUT using table views.  Table views use row at index path to point to the correct object (row).  I am using the Fetched Results controller with a predicate to retrieve the fetched object (row) Question: How do I obtain the index of the fetched row so that I can retrieve and then update the correct property values?  All books and examples use table views to change properties.

```
Entity Product
Product *product;
______________________________   

[self setupFetchedResultsController];        (This returns one object)

product = [NSFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];  (objectAtIndexPath - Errors of course)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you shouldn't use `NSFetchedResultsController` in this case. If you don't want to use it in either a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView`, you're probably better of without it. You're probably better of using a `NSFetchRequest` instead, it's pretty easy to set up:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"someValue=1"];
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Now you have a `NSArray` with all the results, which you could use without having to deal with index paths.

If you're still using a `NSFetchedResultController` for a table (I'm not sure if you do), those rows will still be updated whenever you make a change.

**Update:** To update one of the objects returned by the fetch, could be done like this:

```
Entity *entity = [array firstObject];
[entity setSomeProperty:@"CoreDataIsAwesome"];

NSError *error = nil;
if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Entity updated!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Something went wrong: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: I second this. An NSFetchedResultsController is great when its delegate is coupled to a tableview, and you are planning to display multiple results. For your case, a FetchRequest is a better option.

Comment: Thanks for help Guido.  Arrays are useful for retrieving the properties, but I need to update the properties as well.  I need to retrieve an object and, increment the property by one. then save the new value.

Comment: Thanks again Guido, the first line worked fine.  However the set and save didn't
            Product *product = [productArray firstObject];
            [product setVendor: @"CoreDataIsAwesome"];  (Unrecognized selector) runtime error
            [self.managedObjectContext save];  (no visible interface for NSManagedObjectContext declares the selector save) compile error

Comment: Thanks again Guido, the first line worked fine.  However the set and save didn't
            Product *product = [productArray firstObject];
            [product setVendor: @"CoreDataIsAwesome"];  (Unrecognized selector) runtime error
            [self.managedObjectContext save];  (no visible interface for NSManagedObjectContext declares the selector save) compile error

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `indexPathOfObject:` on your fetched results controller to return the index path of the given object to then do your updates.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Patrick!  Could you provide a little more help please?   I replaced objectAtIndexPath with indexPathOfObject which gave the error:  No known class method for selector "indexPathOfObject"   Probably a basic mistake on my part.  Would be grateful if you could connect the dots for me!  John

Comment: you are attempting to call methods on the Class NSFetchedResultsController instead of an instance of one. Instead, alloc init an instance of that class and call the methods on that instance